# Retrieving SalesForce contact activity history

Tags: javascript, salesforce, soql

I'm working with the JSForce library to interact with SalesForce via JavaScript and i'm running into some issues that I haven't been able to figure out quite yet. My goal is to pull recent activity histories for a contact, so that I can display their "actions" in our 3rd party app. I have tried a few different methods...
Using the Chatter API, but this only returns data for "Users" in the app, not the actual "contacts" (which is what I'm trying to get)
I've also used a host of variuos queries... such as

`var query = "SELECT (SELECT ActivityDate, Description, WhoId, Subject, OwnerId from ActivityHistories) FROM AccountFeed WHERE ParentId = '" + id + "'";`

and

`var query = "SELECT ID, CreatedDate, CreatedById, CreatedBy.FirstName, CreatedBy.LastName, ParentId, Parent.Name, (SELECT ID, FieldName, OldValue, NewValue FROM FeedTrackedChanges ORDER BY ID DESC) FROM UserProfileFeed WITH UserId = '" + id + "' ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC, Id DESC LIMIT 20"`

Any guidance y'all could offer would be greatly appreciated!
thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You may find useful information in [StackExchange for SalesForce](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/8333) in order to retrieve `ActivityHistory`.  Note however that even with this link, I got problems too.

First, you have to identified what are the kind of user accounts in the system you're targeting.  In the link, it's `Account`; for me, it was `Contact`.

Secondly, the system may have some limits and constraints about the retrieving of such information.  In my case for example, there was 2 constraints:

- limit to 500 (`MALFORMED_QUERY: There is an implementation restriction on ActivityHistories. When you query this relationship, security evaluation is implemented for users who don't have administrator permissions, and you must specify a LIMIT with a maximum of 500`)
- need specific filters (`MALFORMED_QUERY: There is an implementation restriction on ActivityHistories. When you query this relationship, security evaluation is implemented for users who don't have administrator permissions, and you must use a specific sort order: ActivityDate DESC, LastModifiedDate DESC`)

In the end, this was my query.

```
SELECT Name, (SELECT Subject,ActivityDate,ActivityType,ActivitySubtype,Description,Status FROM ActivityHistories ORDER BY ActivityDate DESC, LastModifiedDate DESC LIMIT 100) FROM Contact WHERE Id = 'abcde'
```